# Read XML Data as output from a stored procedure in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure which sends XML as output.

I can read that output using ADO.NET by using `SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader` but in EF Core, I am not able to do that same thing.

I have tried by `FromSql` and `ExecuteSqlCommand` method but no success.

Comment: You aren't loading any objects so why use EF Core? EF Core is an *ORM*, not a generic data access method - it maps objects to relational data.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?